# Jest/Enzyme: Mock function in Functional Component

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, enzyme

I have a functional component in React. Here is the code

```
import React, { useState, Fragment } from "react";
import { makeStyles } from "@material-ui/core/styles";
import "./K8sIPCalculator.css";
import { initialState, checkBoxLabel } from "./FormMetaData";
import { checkPositiveInteger } from "./FormDataValidation";

const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
  // Styles
}));

const K8sIPCalculator = (props) => {
  const classes = useStyles();
  let intialStateCopy = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(initialState));
  const [data, setData] = useState(intialStateCopy);

  const handleCheckBox = (path, value) => {
    const newData = { ...data };
    if (path === "nodes" || path === "pods") {
      if (!checkPositiveInteger(value)) {
        newData[path].value = value;
        newData[path].helperText = "It should be a positive integer!";
      } else {
        newData[path].value = value;
        newData[path].helperText = "";
      }
    } else newData[path] = value;
    setData(newData);
  };

  const calculate = () => {
           // Does some calculation and update data state
  };

  const onSubmit = () => {
    if (data.nodes.helperText !== "" || data.pods.helperText !== "") {
      alert("Data is not correct");
      return;
    }
    calculate();
  };

  const onReset = () => {
    intialStateCopy = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(initialState));
    setData(intialStateCopy);
  };

  return (
    <Fragment>
      <h2 className="name">K8s IP Calculator</h2>
      <form className={classes.formRoot}>
        <Accordion
          defaultExpanded={true}
          classes={{ expanded: classes.expanded }}
        >
          <AccordionSummary
            expandIcon={<ExpandMoreIcon />}
            id="accordion1"
            className={classes.summary}
          >
            <Typography className={classes.heading}>Results</Typography>
          </AccordionSummary>
          <AccordionDetails className="container">
            <InputLabel className={classes.label}>
              Total useable IPs required:
            </InputLabel>
            <TextField
              disabled
              className={classes.textDisabledInput}
              id="ips-required-output"
              variant="outlined"
              value={data.total}
            />
            <InputLabel className={classes.label} htmlFor="subnet-size-output">
              Subnet Size required:
            </InputLabel>
            <TextField
              disabled
              className={classes.textDisabledInput}
              id="subnet-size-output"
              variant="outlined"
              value={data.subnet_size}
            />
          </AccordionDetails>
        </Accordion>
        <br />
        <Accordion
          defaultExpanded={true}
          classes={{ expanded: classes.expanded }}
        >
          <AccordionSummary
            expandIcon={<ExpandMoreIcon />}
            id="accordion2"
            className={classes.summary}
          >
            <Typography className={classes.heading}>K8s Details</Typography>
          </AccordionSummary>
          <AccordionDetails className="container">
            <InputLabel className={classes.label}>Nodes:</InputLabel>
            <TextField
              size="small"
              type="number"
              onChange={(e) => handleCheckBox("nodes", e.target.value)}
              className={classes.textInput}
              id="nodes-input"
              variant="outlined"
              value={data.nodes.value}
              helperText={data.nodes.helperText}
            />
            <InputLabel className={classes.label} htmlFor="pods-input">
              Pods:
            </InputLabel>
            <TextField
              size="small"
              type="number"
              onChange={(e) => handleCheckBox("pods", e.target.value)}
              className={classes.textInput}
              id="pods-input"
              variant="outlined"
              value={data.pods.value}
              helperText={data.pods.helperText}
            />
            <div id="nodes-error"></div>
          </AccordionDetails>
        </Accordion>
        <div className="button-container">
          <Button
            id="reset-button"
            className="button"
            variant="outlined"
            color="primary"
            size="small"
            onClick={onReset}
            startIcon={<UndoIcon />}
          >
            Reset
          </Button>
          <Button
            id="submit-button"
            className="button"
            variant="contained"
            color="primary"
            size="small"
            startIcon={<SaveIcon />}
            onClick={onSubmit}
          >
            Submit
          </Button>
        </div>
      </form>
    </Fragment>
  );
};

export default K8sIPCalculator;
```

Things, I am trying to test,

1. When input changes, I want to check if handleCheckBox function has been called
2. When submit button is called, I want to check if calculate function has been called
3. How can I call the setData function to update data through Jest/Enzyme

I tried something like this

```
const spy = jest.spyOn(K8sIPCalculator, "calculate");
```

But I got

```
Cannot spy the calculate property because it is not a function; undefined given instead
```

PS: I am able to assert data change after submit is called. But I want to check if calculate function is called.

```
    const submit = wrapper.find("button#submit-button");
    submit.simulate("click");

    expect(wrapper.find("input#ips-required-output").props().value).toEqual(35);
    expect(wrapper.find("input#subnet-size-output").props().value).toEqual(
      "/26"
    );
```

Comment: Those are **not** good tests. Don't test whether the function has been called (you don't have access to them anyway - they're nested, they aren't properties of the function), that's implementation; test the *behaviour*. Instead of testing that `handleCheckBox` was called, for example, test that **the rendered elements changed appropriately** to reflect the expected change in the component's state (don't test the state directly, either).

Comment: @jonrsharpe Thanks for your response. So We won't be able to test any function inside the functional component?

Comment: No, that's not what I'm saying at all. You test those functions by testing that the component implements the expected behaviour, rather than coupling to the implementation and asserting on how those functions get called (which you can't do anyway, because they're inaccessible outside the function).